# Location issue while browse the query

Tags: discussion

I have just updated my location in my profile. It is updated in all community. But when I try to browse query then still it display my old location.

I have changed "Surat" to "Rajkot" location in my profile. When I tried to browse following query on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new.

```
SELECT TOP 50
   Id,
   DisplayName,
   Reputation,
   WebsiteUrl,
   Location
FROM
   Users
WHERE
   Location like N'%Surat%'
ORDER BY
   reputation DESC
```

It still display my name in "Surat" location.

My question is why location is not changed?